# groupby/eq compute mean of specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to figure out to how to use groupby/eq to computer the mean of specific column, i have a df as seen below (original df).

I would like to groupby 'Group' and 'players' with class equals 1 and get the mean of the 'score'.
example:

Group = a, players =2
(16+13+19)/3 = 16

```
+-------+---------+-------+-------+------------+
| Group | players | class | score | score_mean |
+-------+---------+-------+-------+------------+
| a     |       2 |     2 |    14 |            |
| a     |       2 |     1 |    16 |         16 |
| a     |       2 |     1 |    13 |         16 |
| a     |       2 |     2 |    13 |            |
| a     |       2 |     1 |    19 |         16 |
| a     |       2 |     2 |    17 |            |
| a     |       2 |     2 |    14 |            |
+-------+---------+-------+-------+------------+
```

i've tried:

```
df['score_mean'] = df['class'].eq(1).groupby(['Group', 'players'])['score'].transform('mean')
```

but i kept getting "KeyError"

original df:

```
+----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
|    | Group | players | class | score |
+----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
|  0 | a     |       1 |     1 |    10 |
|  1 | c     |       2 |     1 |    20 |
|  2 | a     |       1 |     3 |    29 |
|  3 | c     |       1 |     3 |    22 |
|  4 | a     |       2 |     2 |    14 |
|  5 | b     |       1 |     2 |    16 |
|  6 | a     |       2 |     1 |    16 |
|  7 | b     |       2 |     3 |    17 |
|  8 | c     |       1 |     2 |    22 |
|  9 | b     |       1 |     2 |    23 |
| 10 | c     |       2 |     2 |    22 |
| 11 | d     |       1 |     1 |    13 |
| 12 | a     |       2 |     1 |    13 |
| 13 | d     |       1 |     3 |    23 |
| 14 | a     |       2 |     2 |    13 |
| 15 | d     |       2 |     1 |    34 |
| 16 | b     |       1 |     3 |    32 |
| 17 | c     |       2 |     2 |    29 |
| 18 | b     |       2 |     2 |    28 |
| 19 | a     |       2 |     1 |    19 |
| 20 | a     |       1 |     1 |    19 |
| 21 | c     |       1 |     1 |    27 |
| 22 | b     |       1 |     3 |    47 |
| 23 | a     |       2 |     2 |    17 |
| 24 | c     |       1 |     1 |    14 |
| 25 | c     |       2 |     2 |    25 |
| 26 | a     |       1 |     3 |    67 |
| 27 | b     |       2 |     3 |    21 |
| 28 | a     |       1 |     3 |    27 |
| 29 | c     |       1 |     1 |    16 |
| 30 | a     |       2 |     2 |    14 |
| 31 | b     |       1 |     2 |    25 |
+----+-------+---------+-------+-------+
```

```
data = {'Group':['a','c','a','c','a','b','a','b','c','b','c','d','a','d','a','d',
               'b','c','b','a','a','c','b','a','c','c','a','b','a','c','a','b'],
      'players':[1,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1],
                'class':[1,1,3,3,2,2,1,3,2,2,2,1,1,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,1,2,3,3,3,1,2,2],
      'score':[10,20,29,22,14,16,16,17,22,23,22,13,13,23,13,34,32,29,28,19,19,27,47,17,14,25,67,21,27,16,14,25]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

kindly advice

Many thanks & Regards

Comment: kindly post the expected output

Comment: hi, the expected output can be seen in the first df (shorter). thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Via `set_index()`,`groupby()` ,`assign()` and `reset_index()` method:

```
df=(df.set_index(['Group','players'])
   .assign(score_mean=df[df['class'].eq(1)].groupby(['Group', 'players'])['score'].mean())
   .reset_index())
```

### Update:

If you want the first `df` as your output then use:

```
grouped=df.groupby(['Group', 'players','class']).transform('mean')
grouped=grouped.assign(players=df['players'],Group=df['Group'],Class=df['class']).where(df['Group']=='a').dropna()
grouped['score']=grouped.apply(lambda x:float('NaN') if x['players']==1 else x['score'],1)
grouped=grouped.dropna(subset=['score'])
```

Now if you print `grouped` you will get your desired output

Comment: there's an "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" when using 1st method, however, the 2nd method works. thanks. fyi, there were some error in my original df which i've just updated

Comment: Ohh...You changed your data..If second method is working as per your need...so I removed the 1st method in answer

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon  Updated answer....Kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, need values returned only where class=1. Not sure what that will serve but code below. Use groupby transform and chain where

```
df['score_mean']=df.groupby(['Group','players'])['score'].transform('mean').where(df['class']==1).fillna('')

   Group  players  class  score score_mean
0      a        1      1     10         10
1      a        2      1     20         20
2      a        3      5     29           
3      a        4      5     22           
4      a        5      5     14           
5      b        1      7     16           
6      b        2      7     16           
7      b        3      7     17           
8      c        1      4     22           
9      c        2      2     23           
10     c        3      2     22           
11     d        1      4     13           
12     d        2      4     13           
13     d        3      3     23           
14     d        4      8     13           
15     d        5      7     34           
16     e        1      7     32           
17     e        2      2     29           
18     e        3      2     28           
19     e        4      1     19         19
20     e        5      1     19         19
21     e        6      1     27         27
22     f        1      5     47           
23     f        2      5     17           
24     f        3      7     14           
25     f        4      7     25           
26     g        1      3     67           
27     g        2      3     21           
28     g        3      3     27           
29     g        4      8     16           
30     g        5      8     14           
31     g        6      8     25
```

Comment: there were some errors in my original df(sorry) which i've updated. the computation of the means seems off which the corrected original df

Comment: I am not clear what you mean. Please clarify

Comment: with the corrected df, Group = a, players =2 (16+13+19)/3 = 16, however using the code you've provided the score_mean = 15.1428571428571. once again, i apologize for the error in my original df.

Answer (score 0):

You could first filter by class and then create score_mean by doing a groupby and transform.

```
(
    df[df['class']==1]
    .assign(score_mean = lambda x: x.groupby(['Group', 'players']).score.transform('mean'))
)

    Group   players class   score   score_mean
0   a       1       1       10      14.5
1   c       2       1       20      20.0
6   a       2       1       16      16.0
11  d       1       1       13      13.0
12  a       2       1       13      16.0
15  d       2       1       34      34.0
19  a       2       1       19      16.0
20  a       1       1       19      14.5
21  c       1       1       27      19.0
24  c       1       1       14      19.0
29  c       1       1       16      19.0
```

If you want to keep other classes and set the mean to '', you can do:

```
(
    df[df['class']==1]
    .groupby(['Group', 'players']).score.transform('mean')
    .pipe(lambda x: df.assign(score_mean = x))
    .fillna('')
)
```